# Redirection non-www to www But bypass the static.domain.com url?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need my domain.com to redirect to www.domain.com.
But for getting my static content from a cookieless domain, I am hosting a personal CDN on my same domain as static.domain.com.

Now when I run this condition in .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works fine if user enters  domain.com or htts://domain.com, it will be redirected to htts://www.domain.com.

But the major problem arrived when it redirects even static.domain.com to htts://www.static.domain.com 
Resulting in error on page...

Please guide me how to fix this issue, i am new to rewrite rules in htaccess file.

Thank you :)

Comment: What about changing `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.` into `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.%{HTTP_HOST}` ? .. iam not sure don't have access to a Apache server now.

Comment: thanks @RaymondNijland But it redirected me to www.www.domain.com or www.static.domain.com again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an additional `RewriteCond` to handle the `static` case:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work, still sending static.domain.com to www.static.domain.com ..

Comment: ok finally worked, i had some sintax error :) thank you so much :D

Comment: spell mistake : syntax*